# getting garbage string (gibberish) at browser

Tags: c#, sql, json, google-chrome, utf-8

I have a class in WebService.asmx that return DATA from SQL in JSON format to 
the browser.

The problem at the 'string's, the INTEGER's looks fine.

The output looks like that:

```
[{"code":21,"acc_name":"×ž×“×¢×ª ×ž×™×—×©×•×‘","contact_name":"××ª×™","mobile_phone":"","phone1":"089463393"}
```

The problem happens at the other browsers too. I have to mention that the CLASS works fine several months until yesterday.

Comment: You need to provide some sample data, ideally along with the query and code used to generate your JSON output. Update your question with that information and perhaps we can help

Comment: hey Christian,
here is the WebServise code:
''